# I would like to do two things at the same time in delphi, for example, run two timer events simultaneously

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timer

I would like to do two things at the same time in delphi, for example, to run at the same time as the two-timer,,,,How to use a method that?

For example, let's look at this simple example, here are two timers and these timers running consecutively but I would like to run the timers at the same time,,,but how?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

if Button1.Caption = 'START' then
  begin
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
  Timer2.Enabled := True;
  Button1.Caption := 'FINISH'
  end
else if Button1.Caption = 'FINISH' then
  begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Timer2.Enabled := False;
  Button1.Caption := 'START';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
i : integer;
begin
for i := 0 to 50 do
  begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i));
  sleep(500);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
k : integer;
begin
for k := 0 to 50 do
  begin
  Memo2.Lines.Add(IntToStr(k));
  sleep(500);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: What is a 'two-timer'? Generally, the way to do two things at once is to run two threads at once, although even then depending on your system they may only *appear* to run at the same time. Searching SO or Google for Delphi thread examples will help. Beyond that, can you explain in much more detail what you want to do?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You need to spend some time to get your thoughts clear and ask a real question.

Comment: ----two timer or running at the same time in two different code, I'm looking at the examples on thread but I could not find an example of how two different timers to run at the same time. I do not know much about it, I'd appreciate if you help me.

Comment: We'd like to help you. But that's going to require you to ask a real question. What are you asking? Make it clear. In order to get help you are going to need to put some effort in.

Comment: I made a simple example to explain the situation, How can I send you the exe file and the source code

Comment: @Muammer, post your code in the question.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630686/delphi-7-how-to-implement-multi-threading   Also: http://delphi.about.com/od/kbthread/ http://forum.codecall.net/topic/70827-very-simple-multithreading/ otl.17slon.com/‎

Answer (score 3):

> " I would like to run the timers at the same time,,,but how?"

This is not possible.

Everything in the main thread is running in one sequence.
There is no way to run two procedures at the same time, even using timers.

The idle part of the main thread checks the message queue for messages.
They are handled one by one. This is what is happening when your timer events are called.
During the execution of your timer event, the main thread does nothing but execute this event.

So be careful with the complexity of your timer event code and keep it short and simple.

If you want better multitasking performance (or your timer event is too complex), you must use [`threads`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TThread).
Threads are executed "parallel" to your main thread with their own stack.
How parallel is interpreted depends on the OS and also how many cores the CPU has.

Access to the VCL part from your threads is not possible without proper protection, like [`Synchronize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize).
This means that the thread waits until the synchronized part has been executed in the main thread.
It is also possible to [`queue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) messages asynchronously from the thread to be executed main thread.

You can find an example of multithreading in the Delphi samples, [`ThrdDemo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/RTL.Threads_Sample).

Comment: hmm, I get it. But I don't know too much of Thread, so I have to study,,,,thank you.

Comment: Free advice;  Learn to write non-threaded code and be a pretty experienced developer before you try using threads.

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `Sleep` inside the `TTimer.OnTimer` handler. Instead, set yout timer interval to 500 and it will fire every 500 miliseconds. Both timers will fire and you will have a sensation that two things are running at the same time.

It´s an ilusion, however, since both codes are running inside the same thread (the main thread), but depending on your requirements, the behavior may be acceptable.

Comment: I called sleep because it does not work at the same time on the screen to view the timer1 and timer 2. so 'sleep' is not important, what is important for me to work at the same time timers

Comment: @Muammer: ok, as I said, using two timers to simulate two threads (two lines of execution at the same time) has several limitations. It requires that the code in `TTimer.OnTimer` to be really fast, for while it´s running, nothing else will, including the other timer. Keep doing your experiments, but I advise you to take the idea of studing threads seriously.